# Filling up vertical gaps with html bootstrap (rows)

Tags: html, row

What I want is hard to say it in words, so I'll just attach a picture to show what I want

[image]

Basically, if there is space above a col, it should adjust it's height so there is no gap anymore.

```
<div class="row text-center mx-auto" id="contentRow">
    <div class="col-sm-4 align-items-stretch" >
    <div class="text-start flex-column" style="font-size: 15px">
        <p><u><strong>Basic Tags</strong></u></p>
    </div>
    Text content blablabla
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-4 align-items-stretch" >
    <div class="text-start flex-column" style="font-size: 15px">
        <p><u><strong>Advanced Tags</strong></u></p>
    </div>
    Even longer text content that is taller than before blablabla
        lorem ipsum and idk how it goes on
    </div>
    //And some more rows so they get auto-put into new rows.
</div>
```

This works pretty well, but it doesn't satisfy my needs. I think it basically makes the cols in each row the same height, which is not really what I want.